# What CMSes offer an "Import from wordpress" feature

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, migration

After 2 (very) painful years of using Wordpress and fighting a constant stream of bugs and vulnerabilities, I've decided I absolutely have to move to a different platform.

What CMSes offer a smooth migration path from Wordpress (I.e, page, post, and comment importing)?

I would greatly prefer a CMS written in ruby or python, so that I can extend it easily.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Free options

[Movable Type](http://www.movabletype.org/) is another great option for a CMS and it's highly used. I have seen a lot of people that migrated to it from Wordpress without problems.

[Drupal](http://drupal.org/) has an official plugin to import from Wordpress. It's a great CMS/Framework to work with.

### Paid options

I don't know anyone that migrated from WP to [Expression Engine](http://expressionengine.com/), but a quick search showed some good points on it.

[VBulletin](https://www.vbulletin.com/) Suite (which includes the CMS and the forums), is a great tool and ImpEX, their official import tool (no additional charges for that) is great and flawless on transitioning. I have worked for years with VBulletin, it's a great plataform, but never tried on a production scale using their CMS Suite.